# Error in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a iframe with a youtube video in my slider, he starts to auto playing in the slide and then after 20 seconds he stops playing and change for another slider with another info. In chrome and firefox the slider works fine, but in **safari** the video don't hide, he continues appearing in other sliders. What could i do?

http://cooptaxis.pt/index_teste.php

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var revapi;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
{
delay:20000,
startwidth:1170,
startheight:500,
hideThumbs:10,
});

$('.tp-bullets').find('div.bullet').bind('click', function(){
var url = $('.video1').attr('src');
url = url.replace(/autoplay=1&/g, '');
$('.video1').attr('src', '');
$('.video1').attr('src', url);
});

$('.tparrows').bind('click', function(){
var url = $('.video1').attr('src');
url = url.replace(/autoplay=1&/g, '');
$('.video1').attr('src', '');
$('.video1').attr('src', url);
});
}); //ready
</script>


<div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner" >
            <ul>    
                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500" >
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
        <img src="images/slide/ponte.png"  alt="ponte"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                  <div class="tp-caption customin skewtoleft"
                        data-x="125"
                        data-y="15"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="600"
                        data-start="1500"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="400"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 1"><img src="images/slide/taxiclick-1.png" alt="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption skewfromleft"
                        data-x="644"
                        data-y="40"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="2200"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 2"><img src="images/slide/smartphone.png" alt="">
                    </div>



                    <!-- LAYER NR. 7 -->

                <div class="tp-caption customin customout"
                        data-x="center" data-hoffset="230"
                        data-y="center" data-voffset="90"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:5;scaleY:5;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="600"
                        data-start="1000"
                        data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Power4.easeOut"
                        style="z-index: 3">
                <iframe class="video1" width="340" height="260" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yxp4XV-3SLs?autoplay=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                        <!--<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/88055647?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0;api=1' width='340' height='260'
                       style='width:340px;height:260px;'>
            </iframe>-->




                        <!--<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/88055647?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0;api=1' width='340' height='260'
                       style='width:340px;height:260px;'>
            </iframe>-->


                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption skewfromleft"
                        data-x="415"
                        data-y="317"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="2200"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 4"><a href="http://cooptaxis.pt/taxi-click.php"><img src="images/slide/sabermais.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>

                </li>

                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500" >
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="images/slide/slidebg1.jpg"  alt="slidebg1"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin skewtoleft"
                        data-x="665"
                        data-y="14"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="600"
                        data-start="1500"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="400"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 5"><img src="images/slide/raparig2a_.png" alt="">
                    </div>


<div class="tp-caption skewfromleft"
                        data-x="90"
                        data-y="157"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="2200"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 6"><img src="images/slide/chamar_taxi.png" alt="">
                    </div>



                </li>
                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500" >
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="images/slide/slidebg1.jpg"  alt="slidebg1"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                  <div class="tp-caption customin skewtoleft"
                        data-x="505"
                        data-y="0"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="600"
                        data-start="1500"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="400"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 7"><img src="images/slide/rato.png" alt="">
                    </div>


<div class="tp-caption skewfromleft"
                        data-x="110"
                        data-y="157"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="2200"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 8"><img src="images/slide/peca_taxi.png" alt="">
                    </div>



                </li>
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500" >
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="images/slide/slidebg1.jpg"  alt="slidebg1"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                  <div class="tp-caption customin skewtoleft"
                        data-x="405"
                        data-y="0"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="600"
                        data-start="1500"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="400"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 10"><img src="images/slide/taxi.png" alt="">
                    </div>


<div class="tp-caption skewfromleft"
                        data-x="90"
                        data-y="197"
                        data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="2200"
                        data-easing="Back.easeOut"
                        data-endspeed="500"
                        data-endeasing="Back.easeIn"
                        style="z-index: 10"><img src="images/slide/2000profissionais.png" alt="">
                    </div>



                </li>




            </ul>
            <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, first try to correct that http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcooptaxis.pt%2Findex_teste.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks! i think is ok now. But the problem continues